# Как сделать на сайте так, чтобы на разных устройствах выполнялись разные html-шаблоны?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, оптимизация-сайтов, мобильные-приложения

Я хочу оптимизировать свой веб-сайт под мобильные устройства. Как мне сделать так, чтобы если ширина и высота экрана меньше опеделëнного значения, то выполняется другой html-шаблон?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Совсем шаблон поменять не получится, сервер мало чего знает об устройстве, максимум это http заголовок User-Agent.

Наилучший вариант это использовать в CSS свойства media, min-width, max-width.

Comment: Спасибо большое!